# How can I modify Vim to work with a different keyboard layout?

Tags: vimrc, keyboard-layout, key-bindings

I type with a non-QWERTY keyboard layout. Many of the keys Vim uses are now on the home row, but some key bindings just don't work, the most obvious one being the <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> keys.

How and where can I change these key bindings to work better with my keyboard layout?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
:help langmap
```

You can remap keys in command mode but leave them intact for typing. This means you can use the intent of  <kbd>hjkl</kbd> - adjacent homerow keys for scrolling - by pressing the positional equivalents on your keyboard. Suppose your layout is Dvorak, then those same keys are <kbd>dhtn</kbd>. We need to map all four, even <kbd>h</kbd>:

```
:set langmap=dh,hj,tk,nl
```

You can now navigate using <kbd>dhtn</kbd>. This won't affect `:commands like this` and won't change insert mode (i.e. pressing <kbd>t</kbd> will give you a 't').

You'll need to map other keys too for normal mode - for instance, the delete action would normally be <kbd>d</kbd> but that's now a navigation key. <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd> might work since they're no longer navigation keys.

Comment: To be fair, Dvorak uses the keys dhtn, not htns, in the place where Qwerty uses hjkl.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony, I've updated the langmap command to match.

Answer (score 2):

You can remap keys in vim. `nnoremap [ h` remaps `[` to `h`, so you can use `[` in place of `h`, you could remap `h` to what `[` originally did for it to be complete. You'd have to do this for all keys though and there are different modes to consider, so I guess it would be a bit of a pain.

Comment: Since I'll be using vim for at least the next 10 years I'd think it worth the investment. Where do I use this for the change to be reasonably permanent?

Comment: you should put this in your ~/.vimrc